# Is it possible to use car Delivery/Collection indicators with SOAP API?

Tags: .net, soap, sabre

I'd like to be able to perform a Car Location find (CLF command) using the delivery/collection indicator (DC-) via the SOAP API (VehLocationFinderLLSRQ). I can't see a way to add this indicator in the documentation, does anyone know if it's possible?

Here is an example native command from Format Finder:

```
CLF/N-(city name)/C-(country code)/(pick up date)-(drop off date)/(pick up time)-(drop off time)/CD-(Corporate Discount number)/DC-(delivery/collection indicator)

CLF/N-LONDON/C-GB/3JUN-4JUN/9A-5P/CD-ZI1234567/DC-C

Note: The system response to a (D) indicator includes those rental locations which are set for Both (B) or Delivery (D) only.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This enhancement is tentatively scheduled for Sabre Web Service TPFC 2.31.0 release scheduled for Production in July. For more information please stay connected with our Sabre API release notes.

thx

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll look out for the next release